# Guarantee Single Consumer per RabbitMQ Queue

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, consumer

I'm trying to build a "weird" thing using RabbitMQ. I'm saying weird since it looks like contradicts with some of the aspects of RabbitMQ.

I have N number of topics. "topic-1", "topic-2", ..., "topic-N". I also have M number of consumers. M <= N. I want to make sure that at no given time there will be two or more clients subscribing a single topic. Though there can be a client that consumers multiple topics.

What's the best way to achieve that? Would I need extra system like ZooKeeper to achieve that?

Thanks,
Ruben

Comment: Is the rabbitmq setup given or can you alter it? Could you use queues instead of topics? Or direct the topic messages to separate queues as shown in the example on [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html) page? Then it would be easy to have only one subscriber per queue.

Comment: There would still be a need to synchronize subscribers so that they don't subscribe to the same topic. Imagine starting with one that subscribes to 100 topics/queues, and as the load increases spawning more subscribers.

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. But it should not be too complex to build a dictionary where the queues are mapped to the subscribers. And when a new client spawns, unsubscribe from the queue with the old subscriber, subscribe to the new one and update the dictionary.